# Sorting Up-sells in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce

As I know woocommerse is sorting up-sells in random order.
And to sort it by price you need to add this code in your function.php

```
function filter_woocommerce_upsells_orderby( $orderby ) { 
return 'price'; 
}; 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_upsells_orderby', 'filter_woocommerce_upsells_orderby', 10, 1 );
```

It worked for me.
But I couldn`t figure out how to reverse order of up-sells.
This code sorting out products from high to low price, and I need the opposite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is solution:

```
// remove the upsells action using the same priority as original add_action()
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_upsell_display', 15 );
// add my custom upsells function in the same place
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'custom_upsell_display', 15 );
function custom_upsell_display() {
// default parameters:
// woocommerce_upsell_display( $limit = '-1', $columns = 4, $orderby = 'rand', $order = 'desc' )
// call it with my parameters
woocommerce_upsell_display( -1, 4, 'price', 'asc' );
}
```